# How to rewrite this ActiveRecord query to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have this query from Rails code:

```
cars = Car.where('cars.status = 0 AND cars.new = 0')
cars.each do |car|
  SharedCar.create(car_id: car.id, owner_id:  OWNER_ID)
end
```

and I would need to run this query directly to MySQL console. How to create a MySQL that would does the same as the ActiveRecord above?

**EDIT:** Focus is obviously on how to combine the first and second query, not on how to load the fist query in MySQL.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

With `to_sql` method:

```
Car.where('cars.status = 0 AND cars.new = 0').to_sql
# => SELECT * FROM cars WHERE status = 0 AND new = 0;
```

Result Insert query will be

```
INSERT shared_cars (car_id, owner_id)
    SELECT cars.car_id, <owner_id>
    FROM cars WHERE cars.status = 0 AND cars.new = 0
```

Comment: up for using to_sql I believe you can use to_sql to convert the create method to sql as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE status = 0 AND new = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like this in SQL without any Ruby:

```
INSERT INTO shared_cars (car_id, owner_id) 
  SELECT DISTINCT id, <owner_id> FROM cars WHERE status = 0 AND new = 0;
```